# iOS caches the proxy credentials

Tags: ios, http, networking, proxy, http-proxy

I will keep it short and simple. I have a proxy server which requires authentication. Now my problem is when i make a HTTP request, i get authentication challenge, i provide my credentials now iOS never asks for that again.

Does the OS stores this cache somewhere, looks like it. If Yes where ?? How can i delete this cache so that so that i can continue my testing and finish my app development.

I hovered around everywhere but couldn't find no proper documentation regarding this.

Things i have tried -
1. Reset the Network Settings. No Luck :(
2. Deleted installed my app back, again no luck :(.

Not sure what to do now, any help/explanation is appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: Any body with a answer ??